# Synchronous Facade For Asynchronous Request-Response

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

## Context

1. I am receiving a sync request from an external client to my spring boot rest endpoint(`/request`)
2. My rest service makes a sync call to Microservice A
3. After A is finished executing it publishes an event & then returns a response to my rest client
4. The event published by A is being consumed by another microservice B which performs some transaction and sends a response to the restClient endpoint `/success` indicating a success response

## Problem

How do I make my `/request` endpoint wait until `/success` has been hit before returning a response to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Semaphore` for your desired endpoint and `acquire()` when needed.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/semaphore-in-java/